# How to add sum value in datagrid row in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have 14 rows in my datagrid. Last column contains numeric values. The total of the last column value should be placed in the last column of the last row. How can I do this? Please tell the solution. This is my datagrid and i calculate the sum of the last column.

[image: My datagrid]
This is my datatable last column calculation coding:

```
da.Fill(dt);
object obj;
obj = dt.Compute("Sum(TotalDailyExpenses)", "");
```

I want to set this value in last row last column in wpf datagrid

Thanks In Advance

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to add a real `footer row` into a DataGrid. There are hacks like creating a `DataGrid` with no headers and binding the widths to your current `Datagrid` and binding the appropriate column values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this, add a new row to your datatable, set all the values to default (0 for int columns and string.empty for string columns) except "TotalDailyExpenses". In this column you have to put the actual calculated sum of the previous rows. Then follow the same approach that you are following now. It'll help.

Or if you want a hack, this could be the solution.

If you have binded your grid to datatable, then it would be something like this

```
this.datagrid.Items[this.datagrid.Items.Count-1][ColumnName] = desiredValue;
```

or

```
this.datagrid.Items[this.datagrid.Items.Count-1][TotalDailyExpenses] = desiredValue;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give you an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: thanks for ur reply...the column name doesn't give. If i give i got the error. I need the sum of TotalDailyExpenses value is placed below the TotalDailyExpenses column. I done the caluclation part. but i don't know how to place the below the TotalDailyExpenses column...